# Super Strange Ruby, or Rails, Non-Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Given this code block:

```
user.products.where(id: products.map(&:id)).update_all(test_field: "")

products.each do |product|

  if true
    product.test_field = "Made it" 
    product.save!
  end

end
```

`product` is not saved! Also, there is no error. The loop simply continues. In my 7 years of working with Ruby, this is the third time I have seen this, and I have never figured out why this occurs.

Here is the extra strange part. Never mind for a moment that gross `update_all` statement. If I add just one line to the above, so that it looks like this:

```
user.products.where(id: products.map(&:id)).update_all(test_field: "")

products.each do |product|

  if true
    product.test_field = "Made it" 
    product.save!
    puts ''
  end

end
```

**THEN THE SAVE OCCURS**. It's like it jars something loose. I can't explain it. However, if I change:

```
puts ''
```

to just:

```
puts
```

Then the save doesn't happen again. No error or nothing.

Now if I whack the `update_all` statement and move that update within the loop for each product, the save happens just fine without the `puts ''`.

Has anyone ever come across this? This is `ruby-1.9.3-p545`, `Rails 3.2.16`, but I have had this happen 2 other times in the past 4 years.

Comment: Time to get a debugger :) ?

Comment: Interesting... On the second attempt in your work experience, you should let the Rails core developer to know the fact. The workaround you were using in your through out projects, was so nasty. Don't use it that way. Create an issue ticket.

Comment: No-one else will be able to figure this out, unless they can reproduce it on their own machine. But if you've never had to dive into Rails (or even MRI) and debug it, it's not as difficult as you probably think. One shot in the dark: try putting `GC.disable` at the top and see if it makes a difference. If it does, you have found an interpreter bug.

Comment: Whats the States of products before the update_all?

Comment: products had some Description child objects added to it, though not persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also run into this issue once without a 'real' solution, however I was able to work around it:

Change

```
product.test_field = "Made it"
```

to

```
product.update_attributes!(test_field: "Made it")
```

And this should fix the issue.  Although I agree with the comments that somebody should probably report it to the Rails team, I just don't have the motivation to actually do so.